# After filling form with Watin the submit button remains disabled

Tags: javascript, forms, watin

I reask this question because no one could give a answer yet and the problem still remains. After filling a form the submit button remains disabled and I don't know how I can fix it. When I click with my mouse into one inputfield the disabled attribute of the Submit button disappears and it is clickable. I couldn't simulate this mouseclick by the Click() Method for this input field.

This is what I've tried yet:

```
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).Click();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).Focus();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).Select();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).KeyDown();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).KeyUp();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).Change();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("pvpnet-account-email")).Blur();
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I've had this situation before and normally you have to follow the EXACT same pattern as you do as a user of that web page and by this I mean, record EVERY single action you do before that button becomes active. A very important action on some sites is to use .TypeText on some TextFields instead of setting the .Value property as setting the .Value property won't trigger some events on the client side. If this is a web site that it is available to everybody I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript on the web page that enables the button? That could point us to the answer.